# Using arrays&awk - sort the file

Tags: shell

Input file:

```
Ganesh
Gowri
Sam
Dave
Peter
Sheela
```

Output file:

```
Dave
Ganesh
Gowri
Peter
Sam
Sheela
```

Can someone please suggest the script for sorting the above file using arrays & awk...

Comment: Search `man gawk | less +/^' *asort'` & `man gawk | less +/^' *asorti'`

Comment: look at other questions here at stackoverflow - it is always better to write explicitly what kind of script you would like to deploy as well as describe by words what you'd like to achieve (alphabet sorting)

Answer (score 2):

array & awk: **`asort()`**

```
kent$  echo "Ganesh
Gowri
Sam
Dave
Peter
Sheela"|awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{asort(a);for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}'
Dave
Ganesh
Gowri
Peter
Sam
Sheela
```

array & awk: **`asorti()`**

```
kent$  echo "Ganesh
Gowri
Sam
Dave
Peter
Sheela"|awk '{a[$0]}END{asorti(a);for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' 
Dave
Ganesh
Gowri
Peter
Sam
Sheela
```

Comment: How we can sort the lower and upper case alphabets using Awk command in Unix?